# Triggering An Event At Certain Dates Android

Tags: android

i am currently developing an auction app. each item will have a time frame before the auction ends on that item. i was wondering if anyone can give me an idea on how to listen to each item and check if the auction time has ended on that given item. 
should i use a Service and build in it a trigger every second that checks each item in the database?
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did for a previous app to solve a similar issue was to include the date/timestamp of the end date, and then implement a handler to implement a countdown until that date/time.

```
    UpdateDisplay();

    handler.removeCallbacks(updateTimeTask);
    handler.postDelayed(updateTimeTask, 1000);  
    }

    private Runnable updateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    UpdateDisplay();
    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    Log.i(TAG, "End of updateTimeTask");
    }
    };
```

And inside `UpdateDisplay()` I kept the code for updating the UI, based on some logic subtracting the current time from the time remaining to show a second hand ticking down.

Comment: so i fetch all the items ending date into an array for example and in this handler i check every second if the current date is equal to any of the dates in the array?